# Linux sees only a single cpu core out of 6 available cores

Tags: linux, acpi, nixos

My linux system does not boot if I don't append `acpi=off` to the kernel params.

I think the reason that the os does not see all of the CPU cores is this param. But I can not remove it; because it won't boot and the error is:

```
ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [CAP1] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Bugger (64 bits) 
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error
```

I tried many ways not to append the `acpi=off` but I didn't make it to boot properly.

```
➜  ~ lscpu | egrep 'Model name|Socket|Thread|NUMA|CPU\(s\)'
CPU(s):                          1
On-line CPU(s) list:             0
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz
Thread(s) per core:              1
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0

➜  ~ uname -a                                                         
Linux nixos 5.15.52 #1-NixOS SMP Sat Jul 2 14:41:19 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: ACPI errors are "normal". They usually do not interrupt the boot process either. Are you sure yours does?

Comment: @DanielB Yes I'm sure. It will stuck on boot if I don't append `acpi=off` in kernel params.

Comment: That doesn't say anything about your system not detecting all cpu cores.

Comment: @JustKhaithang Updated the question

Comment: yes, acpi=off is likely causing the issue, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623363/multi-core-linux-workstation-recognizes-only-1-cpu-1-core-1-thread

Comment: maybe try figuring out why the system is not booting unless acpi is off, since acpi errors don't usually keep a system from booting

Comment: @Esther What should I do? I cannot remove it. I tried so many times in many ways to remove `acpi=off` but it will not boot without it.

Comment: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207867 it's apparently a known bug, which kernel version are you using?

Comment: can you update your BIOS?

Comment: Perhaps helpful: https://askubuntu.com/q/1075498/1366419

Comment: @Esther Added the output of `uname -a` to the question. I did try to update my BIOS but there is no newer version. I rolled back to an older version but it did not solve the problem. I did upgrade back to the newest.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I already have checked and tried it Saaru. thanks anyway.

Comment: did you try `acip=ht`? that will allow all cores and disable the rest of ACPI. Otherwise try Ubuntu and install `firmware-linux-nonfree` which may fix it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to [include what you've looked into so far](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) as otherwise people might keep suggesting things you've tried already (and which didn't work). That would be a waste of time.

Comment: @Esther Yes I did

Comment: also you can try resetting your BIOS. Or changing some options, for example what [this person did]9https://askubuntu.com/questions/247028/how-to-fix-that-only-one-out-of-four-cores-of-my-cpu-is-detected). Also listing exact hardware would help, since ACPI errors are partially because motherboard manufacturers don't implement ACPI properly.

Comment: @Esther I tried live usb ubuntu and live usb arch. They were also single core too.

Comment: of course. `acpi=off` will *always* only allow 1 core. You have to be able to figure out how to boot without it.